# not able to spot error

Tags: android

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FluteActivity extends Activity {
        Button btn;
        TextView tv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv.setText(new Date().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

i am not able to find error and can some one tell me where to look for when run time error occurs as i have no idea about debugging.

Comment: You'll need to at least post the stacktrace that you are getting...

Comment: What error occurs? A quick guess would be that you try to cast a textView to a Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace this line: `tv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.textView1);`,

by this line: `tv=(Textview)findViewById(R.id.textView1);`